# Cannot add YouTube video to wordpress page. Why?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube

I'am trying to upload a YouTube video in standart way. Copy the video url, paste it in the WordPress Visual Box. I see the video is appearing, but after updating the page, there's no video. Why this happens ?Am i miss something ?

Comment: try pasting the embed code on your site instead.

Comment: I did it. Doesn't work

Comment: when you paste embed code what is the response you got.